# Trying to write a QGIS processing script for 'native:hublines', cannot seem to get it working

Tags: qgis, hub-lines

I have an almost functioning script (I think) to draw hub lines in QGIS, but cannot get the last bit to function properly. Here is my script:

```
 from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QVariant
 from qgis.core import (QgsProcessing,
                       QgsFeatureSink,
                       QgsFeature,
                       QgsField,
                       QgsFields,
                       QgsProcessingException,
                       QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink,
                       QgsProcessingParameterField)
from qgis import processing



class best_tower(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    
    hubs = 'hub_layer'
    hub_field = 'hub_field'
    spokes = 'spokes_layer'
    spokes_field = 'spokes_field'
    output_hubline = 'output_hubline'

    

    def tr(self, string):
        return QCoreApplication.translate('Processing', string)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def createInstance(self):
        return best_tower() 

    def name(self):
        return "Atoll_HubLines"

    def displayName(self):
        return self.tr("Atoll Hub Lines")

    def group(self):
        return self.tr('scripts')

    def groupID(self):
        return 'scripts'


    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):

        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
                self.hubs,
                self.tr("Hub Layer"),
                [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry]
                )
            )

        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterField(
                self.hub_field,
                self.tr("Hub ID Field"),
                '',
                self.hubs
                )
            )

        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
                self.spokes,
                self.tr("Spoke Layer"),
                [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry]
                )
            )

        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterField(
                self.spokes_field,
                self.tr("Spoke ID Field"),
                '',
                self.spokes
                )
            )

        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink(
                self.output_hubline,
                self.tr("Output Hublines"),
                type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry
                )
            )


    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):

        source_hubs = self.parameterAsSource(
            parameters,
            self.hubs,
            context
        )

        hubField = self.parameterAsString(
            parameters,
            self.hub_field,
            context
        )

        source_spokes = self.parameterAsSource(
            parameters,
            self.spokes,
            context
        )

        spokesField = self.parameterAsString(
            parameters,
            self.spokes_field,
            context
        )

        fields = QgsFields()
        fields.append(QgsField(hubField, QVariant.String))
        fields.append(QgsField(spokesField, QVariant.String))

        (sink, dest_id) = self.parameterAsSink(
            parameters,
            self.output_hubline,
            context,
            fields,
        )


        # Send some information to the user
        feedback.pushInfo('CRS is {}'.format(source_hubs.sourceCrs().authid()))

        feedback.pushInfo('Hub Parameter is {}'.format(self.hubs))
        feedback.pushInfo('Hub Parameter Field is {}'.format(self.hub_field))
        feedback.pushInfo('Spokes Parameter is {}'.format(self.spokes))
        feedback.pushInfo('Spokes Parameter Field is {}'.format(self.spokes_field))

        
        output = 'C:/temp/HubLines_Data/output.shp'
        hubs = 'C:/temp/HubLines_Data/towers.shp'
        spokes = 'C:/temp/HubLines_Data/civics.shp'
        hub_field = 'hub_field'
        spokes_field = 'spokes_field'
        output_hubline = output
        params = {
            'HUBS':hubs,
            'HUB_FIELD':hub_field,
            'SPOKES':spokes,
            'SPOKE_FIELD':spokes_field,
            'OUTPUT': output
        }
        result = processing.run("native:hublines", params)

        return {self.output_hubline: dest_id}
```

Right now, the error I get is

> "Invalid ID field".

Comment: This is not a python error, indeed? if yes, pots the whole error with line number

Comment: It does not seem to be a python error, as I can run the code in QGIS and input the layers and layer fields for the Hubs and Spokes. After I do that I get the error of not being a valid ID.